# Making a portable version of Robotframework and RIDE, how to make it clean?

Tags: pip, robotframework, robotframework-ide

I want to adapt Robotframework and RIDE to be able to use them on a USB key. In order to achieve this, I planned to use a Portable Version of Python on which I would install all necessary modules using pip.

The main advantage of Portable Python is that it doesn't required any installation on the user's computer, they just have to use the *Console* executable provided by Portable Python to access Python and its modules. A simple insertion of the USB key, and the user would have access to the modules.

Let's say I install Portable Python on a USB key, located on `E:\`. Using `E:\PortablePython\Console-Launcher.exe` which uses command-lines code with all Python related files in the PATH, I manage to install all necessary packages for RobotFramework and RIDE with pip. For example, we can find the *robot.exe* in `E:\PortablePython\App\Python\Scripts` and the python exe is in `E:\PortablePython\App\Python\python.exe` like a usual installation of Python.

Everything works like a charm here, I can run my tests without any issue. The problems come when the key is moved. If I try to run ride on `D:\`:

```
D:\PortablePython>ride.py
Unable to create process using 'E:\PortablePython\App\Python\python.exe "D:\App\Python\Scripts\ride.py" '
```

It actually works if I write :

```
D:\PortablePython>D:\App\Python\python.exe D:\PortablePython\App\Python\Scripts\ride.py
```

But when I try to run tests within RIDE with the robot execution profile, a similar error appears in the console :

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"E:\PortablePython\App\Python\python.exe"  "D:\App\Python\Scripts\robot.exe" --version': Le fichier spÚcifiÚ est introuvable.
```

A workaround is to force the reinstallation of RobotFramework on the USB key to have it use `D:\PortablePython\App\Python\python.exe` instead of `E:\PortablePython\App\Python\python.exe`.

So here are my questions:

- Is there any tweaks available on pip to have packages moveable in a way ? Using relatives paths instead of absolute paths maybe ?
- Is it possible to have execution profiles in RIDE use the python exe on `D:\` instead of the non-existing one on `E:\` ?
- Can virtual environments play a role in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I've been using an incomplete version of a Portable Python. I tried to use [WinPython](https://winpython.github.io/) instead, which has a script making the installation moveable, and it solved all the issues I mentionned.

First I downloaded all the packages and libraries needed to do my tests, then I applied the `make_winpython_movable.bat` provided by WinPython. Everything works now when I move the files or the key.

Answer (score 0):

RIDE uses the $HOME/.robotframework/ride or %APPDATA%\Robotframework\ride directories to create a database of keywords documentation (Help), and the settings.cfg. If you want to preserve this information, you should have a copy in the removable memory, and have some script to create a link to it.

This script may be a better solution to setup RIDE before it is launched. That way you can setup all the needed paths or environment variables, like, for example, `PATH`, `PYTHONPATH`.

If your code is Open Source, you can propose improvements to RIDE's portability, at https://github.com/HelioGuilherme66/RIDE

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Helio. This is the link of Portable Python, it's not my project [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/portable-python/). Would the setting.cfg work if I add this line ```pythonpath = ['%cd%\\App\\Python', '%cd%\\App\\Python\\Scripts']``` ?

Comment: It is not relevant. The database and settings will be created at the user's home. Warning, that project does not have source code available. So we cannot inspect it. Use with care.